# How do I set the background image of a div to include the margins

Tags: html, css, material-design-lite

I am trying to set the background image of a DIV so it covers the whole div, including the margin. I am using the Material Design Lite framework and am trying to set an image background of a div of the class `mdl-cell` so it seems I have a grid of images with no gaps in between. Getting rid of the margins won't work because MDL takes the margin into account when calculating the width of the div, and correcting that would involve modifying too much of MDL.

Here is my code. You can also see/interact with it in [this](https://jsfiddle.net/h1madb61/)

```
.project{
    background-image:url(https://media-cdn.tripadvisor.com/media/photo-s/0e/9a/e3/1d/freedom-tower.jpg);
    height:200px;
}

<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://code.getmdl.io/1.3.0/material.blue_grey-blue.min.css" />
<div class="project-holder mdl-grid">
    <div class="project mdl-cell mdl-cell--3-col" id="cell1">hi</div>
    <div class="project mdl-cell mdl-cell--3-col" id="cell2">hi</div>
    <div class="project mdl-cell mdl-cell--3-col" id="cell3">hi</div>
    <div class="project mdl-cell mdl-cell--3-col" id="cell4">hi</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually margin leave the space from outside boundary so theoretically this is impossible but we can overcome it using pseudo-classes. See following link I updated your css [here][1].

```
  [1]: https://jsfiddle.net/h1madb61/2/
```

Comment: Sweet! Thank you!!